# how to use MVC 3 intellisense for razor in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How i can use Intellisense for Razor in Visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply download and install MVC3 RC1.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your having problems getting it to work and you have the RC installed a long with ReSharper. You have to disable ReSharper's intellisense. [Per this tweet](http://twitter.com/shanselman/status/2263219917819904).

Answer (score 1):

If you were previously using MVC3 Beta and set a file extension association in Visual Studio between .cshtml/.vbhtml and the HTML editor (to get nice HTML colours), then you'll need to remove it before IntelliSense will work with MVC3 RC.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I udnerstand the question. Are you not seeing color highlighting and intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the MVC 3 Release Candidate that was released 9th November.

Download link:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=191797

If you have the RC, then you may have to enable the intellisense by doing the following:

Tools > options > text editor > all languages and make sure intellisense is turned on.
It could be that you have installed a utility like Resharper that might have disabled it.

I hope this helps.